# split the content of a specific column

Tags: text-processing, columns, split

I need to split the content of the second column of my `file` into 2 columns, for example:

```
Id  allele  id2
30  TC  12      
211 GG  12      
327 AA  13      
688 TC  15      
760 TT  18      
868 CC  90
```

The output should be:

```
Id  allele1 allele2 id2
30  T   C   12      
211 G   G   12      
327 A   A   13      
688 T   C   15      
760 T   T   18      
868 C   C   90
```

Comment: Will the second column always be just 2 characters?

Comment: Are the columns separated by "one or more spaces"? Or is that a {tab} you're representing?

Comment: also should this be saved to a new file? or do you just want standard output to terminal?

Comment: yes always 2 characters!

Comment: the columns are separed by tabs

Comment: Yes I need to create a new file

Comment: Alright, my answer has been modified accordingly. Should meet your needs as a simple python script.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{$2=$2"1 "$2"2"} NR!=1{split($2,a,""); $2=a[1]" "a[2];}1' file
```

- `NR==1` applies only for the first line

  - `$2=...`: reformat the second field as header with `allele1 allele2`
- `NR!=1` applies to all other lines.

  - `split($2,a,"")` splits the second field `$2` in array `a`
  - `$2=a[1]" "a[2];`: reformat the second field with the two splitted values `a[1]` and `a[2]`.
- The `1` at the end makes a true condition that `awk` prints the whole (manipulated) line

---

If you want it to be columnated, use this `awk ... | column -t`. The output looks then:

```
Id   allele1  allele2  id2
30   T        C        12
211  G        G        12
327  A        A        13
688  T        C        15
760  T        T        18
868  C        C        90
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file|sed -e 's,\([^ ]*\)[ ]*\(.\)\(.\),\1 \2 \3,' -e '1 s/a llele/allele1 allele2/'
Id allele1 allele2 id2
30 T C  12
211 G G  12
327 A A  13
688 T C  15
760 T T  18
868 C C  90
```

Comment: why fix the first line by hand when you can add `-e '1 s/a llele/allele1 allele2/'` to the `sed` command?

Comment: @cas yes you can. It didn't seem important. I will add, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `sed`:

```sh
sed '1!s/  *./&\t/;t
       s/a.*e/&1 &2/          
'    <infile >outfile
```

You might need to use an actual *<TAB>* character as opposed to the `\t` escape used here.

That works if the columns are divided on spaces. If they are actually *<TAB>* characters dividing the columns, then it needs altering a little.

```sh
sed '1!s/\t./&\t/;t
       s/a.*e/&1 &2/          
'    <infile >outfile
```

...with the same notes as before about possibly needing a literal *<TAB>* in place of the `\`backslash escape.

---

```
Id      allele1 allele2 id
30      T       C       12
211     G       G       12
327     A       A       13
688     T       C       15
760     T       T       18
868     C       C       90
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will take data from your file, split it, and save it to new file.

`./split.py <filename> <newfilename>`

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

file = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
list = file.readlines()

headerstart = list[0].split('\t')
header = headerstart[0] + '\t' + headerstart[1] + '1\t' + headerstart[1] + '2\t' + headerstart[2]


def makeList(input):
        out = []
        for y in list[1:]:
                x = y.split('\t')
                out.append(x[0] + '\t' + x[1][0] + '\t' + x[1][1] + '\t' + x[2])
        return out


file = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

file.write(header)
for x in makeList(list):
        file.write(x)

file.close()
```

you can run it with standard arguments with `./split.py <filename> <newfilename>`

It will take the list of files, split it up based on `\t` tab, then further split the second column in half, and separate by tab and save it to `newfilename`

This answer can be modified to meet other requirements if different information is given.

`output`

```
Id      allele1 allele2 id2

30      T       C       12

211     G       G       12

327     A       A       13

688     T       C       15

760     T       T       18

868     C       C       90
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
perl -lane '$,="  ";@F[1]=~s/./$&  /;print(@F)' in
```

```
 cat in
30  TC  12      
211 GG  12      
327 AA  13      
688 TC  15      
760 TT  18      
868 CC  90 
% perl -lane '$,="  ";@F[1]=~s/./$&  /;print(@F)' in
30  T  C  12
211  G  G  12
327  A  A  13
688  T  C  15
760  T  T  18
868  C  C  90
```